# Alt text for Wagtail images

Tags: wagtail

I'm very new to using Wagtail, but really like it. One problem I'm having is adding alt text, and maybe a credit, to images that I upload. Do I have to create a custom image model to do this?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a custom image model is the best way to attach additional data fields, such as alt text or credits, to an image.

The default Wagtail setup doesn't provide a field for alt text because it isn't really a property of the image, but rather a property of the place where the image is used - it may often be appropriate for the same image to have different alt text on different pages. For that reason, the rich text editor will prompt for alt text at the point where you insert an image into the field; for non-rich-text uses of images, you can do something similar by defining an 'alt text' field alongside the image chooser field.

Comment: That clarifies things a great deal. Thank you.

Comment: @trevore23 I'm not sure what your setup is like but if you use a RichTextBlock you will be able to add an alt text the images you add with it.